# BiMap with uniqueness along the set (key, value)?

Tags: java, guava

I've seen that `BiMap` is for a bidirectional-map, that is link two set.
But does it exists a class that ensures unique-ness along with the set keys and values? (one-to-one relationship) With possibly a unique method `get()`, that is theoretically possible with that. The keys and values have the same class.

Bonus: is `BiMap.inverse()` complexity constant ?

Comment: @andreoss: No.  It's O(1).

Comment: OP: do you mean no key should also be a value?  It's hard to understand what you mean by "uniqueness along with the set keys and values."

Comment: Think like if you  join 1-3, 7-4, etc (arbitrary numbers as exemple and Integer class, but they are unique)... so get(1) should equals to 3, get(7)==4, and get(3)==1, etc...

Answer (score 0):

> ensures unique-ness along with the set keys and values

> keys and values have the same class.

It seems that you need a different data structure, rather than `BiMap`. Have you considered undirected `Graph`[1](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/Graph.html) or `Network`[2](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/Network.html)?

```java
class Person { String name;}
final var john = new Person("John");
final var jane = new Person("Jane");
final MutableGraph<Person> graph = GraphBuilder.undirected().build();
graph.putEdge(john, jane);
Assertions.assertTrue(graph.hasEdgeConnecting(john, jane));
Assertions.assertTrue(graph.hasEdgeConnecting(jane, john));
Assertions.assertEquals(graph.adjacentNodes(jane), Set.of(john));
Assertions.assertEquals(graph.adjacentNodes(john), Set.of(jane));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is an undirectional map, can be implemented for the put/get methods easily.  You can extend to full Map implementation if necessary by delegating to the underlying data.

```
class UndirectionalMap<T> {
    Map<T,T> data = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(T key, T value) {
        data.put(key,value);
        data.put(value,key);
    }

    public T get(T keyOrValue) {
        return data.get(keyOrValue);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
UndirectionalMap<String> map = new UndirectionalMap<>();
map.put("one","1");
map.put("2","two");

System.out.println(map.get("1"));
System.out.println(map.get("2"));
```